# how do i get a java program to recognize which computer its running on?

Tags: java, java-io

I'm making a program that syncs files between my flash drive and 2 computers, however depending on which computer the flash drive is plugged in to, it is either drive G or E. 
How would i get my computer to recognize which computer it is running off of?

Comment: Why don't you simply tell your program, and let it remember it by writing it somewhere (in a file, for example)? Or provide a properties file that your program reads at startup?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of System Properties in java. for example, you can very well make the program to recognize the computer with

```
     //gives the user name
    System.getProperty("user.name");

   //gives the host name or textual representation of ip address
    java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

Once you have the information of the system, you can choose the drive either **G:** or **E:**

The other choice is set a *user defined environment variable* representing the drive name like **FLASH_DRIVE** with the value (G: or E:). YOu can simple send this property using -D option while running your code.say **java -DFLASH_DRIVE yourprogram** and get it using

`System.getProperty("FLASH_DRIVE");`

There are lot of ways you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want automatic detection and not a simple configuration file. There are many, many ways, here's a simple one:

You could just place a file with a unique name on the drive and check for its existence:

```
public String getDrive() {
  String fileName = "unique name.ext";
  String drives = new String[] { "G", "E" }; // Or even all letters
  for(String drive : drives) {
    if(new File(drive + ":\\" + fileName).exists()) {
      return drive;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```